# Соглашение об именовании классов #1

Tags: c#, ооп

Как бы вы назвали/организовали следующую иерархию взаимодействий? Если приложение полностью локальное и нет сетевой части, то название Response актуально? Можно ли показывать класс с Reponse в ViewModel или его еще нужно обработать, чтобы избавиться от Response? Какие есть Best practices?

**Если вас смущает User, то можете придумать любой другой рандомный класс, который надо будет сгенерировать и пачкой добавить в бд.**

Пусть у нас есть некий класс User.

```
public class User
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Далее у нас есть сервис, который генерирует список пользователей:

```
public class UserService
{
    public IReadOnlyCollection<User> GetUsers()
    {

    }   
}
```

На основе данных этого сервиса мы передаем данные в следующий сервис, который должен сохранить коллекцию пользователей в бд.

```
public class UserProcessingService <-- сервис для работы с бд
{
    public async Task SaveUsersAsync(IReadOnlyCollection<User> users)
    {
        //Сохраняем в бд
    }   
}
```

Т.к нам нужно сохранить класс User в бд, то нам требуется добавить как минимум свойство Id в класс User. Но если мы его добавим напрямую в User, то почему UserService должен знать что-либо о бд и о его id? Это протекание слоя данных в бизнес-логику же. В моем понимании этот сервис должен отдавать максимально сжатый класс насколько это возможно без лишних свойств. Поэтому я создаю новый класс. Entity - сущность бд.

```
public class UserEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }    
}
```

User и UserEntity имеют общий код и для синхронизации их свойств создаю интерфейс. Оба класса теперь реализуют этот интерфейс.

```
public interface IUser
{
    public int Age { get; set; }    
}
```

Теперь в методе SaveUsersAsync мы перегоняем коллекцию User в коллекцию UserEntity и сохраняем. Далее я хочу получить коллекцию пользователей из UserProcessingService. Создам возвращаемый класс:

```
public class UserResponse : IUser 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; } 
}
```

И обновим наш ProcessingService

```
public class UserProcessingService
{
    public async Task SaveUsersAsync(IReadOnlyCollection<User> users)
    {
        //Сохраняем в бд
    }   

    //Новый метод
    public async Task<IReadOnlyCollection<UserResponse>> GetUsersAsync()
    {
        //Получаем коллекцию пользователей из бд, маппим и отдаем
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. `UserService` выглядит весьма странным, что за генерация и зачем она тут, я не знаю. Пользователь это конкретный объект, который хранится в базе и из нее получается, а у вас вдруг какая-то генерация, которая потом передается куда-то. 2. `UserProcessingService` - это работа у вас с базой, то есть это CRUD операции, теперь внимание вопрос, почему база вдруг получает один объект, а отдает какой-то `Response`? База обязана получать/отдавать один конкретный объект (в вашем случае это `User`, ну а "маппинг" - это уже не обязанности базы.

Comment: 1. Вместо User можете представить любой рандомный класс. Вот нам нужно что-то сгенерировать и добавить пачкой в бд.
2. UserProcessingService - работа напрямую с Context EF. Это не репозиторий. Ноад этим пунктом подумаю. Спасибо.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ следуя вашей логике метод SaveUsersAsync должен принимать не коллекцию User, а UserEntity. Ему же придется как-то перегонять один тип данных в другой, а это не его обязанность? Это мне перед использованием метода маппить коллекцию User в UserEntity, а после ее получения из GetUsersAsync делать обратное действие? Тогда это не будет нарушением SRP?

Comment: Иногда встречаются такие схемы именования, в которых названия классов в разных слоях всегда одинаковые, но пространства имён (namespace) разные. То есть будут классы `Entities.User`, `Dto.User`, `Models.User`, etc.

Comment: `вашей логике` - это не моя логика, а повсеместная практика. Ну вот ок, сейчас вам надо DTO получить из базы, но что будете делать, если в другом месте, может даже в другом проекте, с другими DTO вам нужно будет получить все теж данные пользователя, но для другого DTO или просто в открытом виде? Вы в своем сервисе сейчас ограничили конкретным `UserResponse`, когда как это все должно быть универсальным и масштабируемым. Ну а "маппинг", я вам уже говорил пример того, как его сделать, простой метод расширения, ну или сделайте оператор и присваивайте DTO к обычному и наоборот, вариантов уйма.

Comment: Даже не задумывался над этим. Для другого DTo добавил бы второй метод. Если делать как вы сказали, то нужно добавлять еще новый класс, который бы перегонял entity в dto. А как его назвать и в каком слое его размещать это уже проблема. Пойду пытать gpt. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вообще избегаю всяких `Service` в названиях классов, потому что это мусор и ничего не значит, `UserService` всё равно что `UserClass`. Понятно только то что там что-то про пользователей, а что именно - непонятно.

Если класс делает CRUD, то он `Manager`. Если класс добывает или формирует данные (например фабрика), то он `Provider`. Например `Manager` может ходить в `Provider`, чтобы поддерживать связь с внешним миром.

Модели данных должны называться просто `User`, `Role`, `PermissionSet`. Допускается иметь одинаково названные классы в разных пространствах имён, но с этим надо быть предельно осторожным и не допускать конфликтов или перепутываний сущностей. Это достигается иерархией пространств имён и модификатором `internal`, чтобы сущности там где не надо, не лезли наружу. Если основной код приложения/сервера не должен напрямую ковырять Entity, то их стоит намеренно изолировать (инкапсулировать).

Вообще сильно с именованием лучше не мудрить и не изобретать ноу-хау, иначе код станет непонятным для других разработчиков (под другим разработчикам можете подразумевать даже себя спустя N-ное количество времени, когда будете напрягаться и вспоминать "что я курил, когда это писал?"). Старайтесь сохранять понятность кода, это и есть основная часть способности писать поддерживаемый код. Чем проще - тем лучше.

Если дотошно соблюдать SOLID, особенно SRP, то проблем с названиями классов не должно быть.